# Replacing a built-in microphone?

Tags: microphone

This question might fall under the "if you have to ask" umbrella, but I have a set of bluetooth headphones that I think would perform a lot better if it was on an arm instead of being built into the ear piece, and I'm wondering if I would be able to hack it so that I could either extend the wire on the microphone and put it at the end of the arm, put in a different microphone, or just put a plastic tube over the mic so sound is funneled to it (like old airplane headsets used to do). The last one is my fallback plan. I'm a junior in Electrical Engineering, and have basic circuit skills.

Comment: Try it - what do you have to lose?

Answer (score 1):

Be warned. Extending the wire would increase the resistance of the line (less if you use huge wire, more if you use super tiny wire like one might) and not the actual microphone causing a degradation in signal, so by moving the mic closer to your mouth it might electrically have less signal after applying all the attenuation added by the increased resistance of the microphone wires.

plastic tube/funnel should work, but that's not really electrical engineering....

Comment: The resistance increase is likely to be negligible. Little capsule electret mics like the one used in the OP's device have an output impedance in the hundreds of ohms anyways. Adding an ohm or two will not be a meaningful change.

Comment: Plastic tube is the engineering part of electrical engineering ;)